# Oracle Trigger Syntax Using Subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I'm trying to write a Trigger in Oracle Syntax which, upon entering a line into a particular table, checks that both values entered belong to some classification that is held in another table. My initial thought was to have a constraint on the table that included a subquery but Oracle doesn't seem to like that.

The select query I have written in the below works - but I'm not sure how to put it into a trigger - but essentially I need the trigger to ensure that EW1.OrgId and EW2.OrgId are the same. Any help is appreciated!

```
CREATE TABLE Organisation (
OrgId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
Name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Person  (
PersonId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
FirstName VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
LastName VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Employee (
PersonId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES PERSON (PersonId) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE Manager (
PersonId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES PERSON (PersonId) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE EnlistedWith (
OrgId INTEGER REFERENCES ORGANISATION (OrgId) ON DELETE CASCADE,
PersonId INTEGER REFERENCES PERSON (PersonId) ON DELETE CASCADE,
PRIMARY KEY(OrgId,PersonId)
);

CREATE TABLE SupervisedBy (
EmployeeId INTEGER REFERENCES Employee (PersonId) ON DELETE CASCADE,
ManagerId INTEGER REFERENCES Manager (PersonId) ON DELETE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT PK_SupervisedBy PRIMARY KEY (EmployeeId, ManagerId)
);

CREATE TRIGGER SupervisorCompany 
AFTER INSERT ON SupervisedBy
   FOR EACH ROW
     BEGIN
       declare qty INTEGER := 0;
            BEGIN
            SELECT COUNT (*) into qty
        FROM SupervisedBy SB
        INNER JOIN EnlistedWith EW1 ON SB.ManagerId = EW1.PersonId
        INNER JOIN EnlistedWith EW2 ON SB.EmployeeId = EW2.PersonId
        and EW1.OrgId <> EW2.OrgId
        IF qty <> 0
        then Raise_Error (1234567, 'Manager and Employee are not Enlisted with same Organisation');
            END IF;
        END;
END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to the columns of the owner of a Trigger using `:NEW / :OLD`. So, your Trigger could be re-written as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER supervisorcompany AFTER 
INSERT 
ON supervisedby FOR EACH ROW 
 DECLARE qty INTEGER := 0; 
BEGIN 
  SELECT count (*) 
  INTO   qty 
  FROM   enlistedwith ew1 
  WHERE  ew1.personid = :NEW.managerid 
  AND    EXISTS 
         ( 
                SELECT 1 
                FROM   enlistedwith ew2 
                WHERE  ew2.personid = :NEW.employeeid 
                AND    ew1.orgid <> ew2.orgid ) ;
IF qty <> 0 THEN 
   raise_application_error (1234567, 'Manager and Employee are not Enlisted with same Organisation');
END IF; 
END;
/
```

Comment: Thanks for responding! I've given this a shot, and unfortunately I'm still getting an error. I'm currently only able to run this in Oracle Live - the error that I'm getting is the same as that for the solution above Error at Line: 15, which just seems to be the last line...

Comment: @Nic : Please edit your question and add sample data or DDL/ DMLs which you used to create the tables in Live sql.

Comment: @Nic : Updated my answer, check now. Remember in Live sql, to see the actual error, run this query : `select * FROM user_errors;` You were using `Raise_Error` - it should be `raise_application_error`

Comment: Thankyou so much!

Answer (score 0):

There's some guessing involved... Maybe something like this

```
CREATE TRIGGER SupervisorCompany 
               AFTER INSERT
               ON SupervisedBy
                  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF (SELECT OrgId
             FROM EnlistedWith
             WHERE PersonId = New.ManagerId)
     <>
     (SELECT OrgId
             FROM EnlistedWith
             WHERE PersonId = New.EmployeeId) THEN
    RAISE_ERROR(1234567, 'Manager and Employee are not Enlisted with same Organisation');
  END IF;
END;
```

is what you want? It checks if the `OrgId` of the row where the `PersonId` equals the newly entered `ManagerId` is the same as the one for the newly entered `EmployeeId`. If not, your error is raised.

(Untested, as no DDL for the tables were provided.)

Comment: Thankyou for responding! - I've tried this and I'm still getting an error. I'm currently only able to run this in Oracle Live so the error is Error at Line: 15, which just seems to be the END;